# SqlAlchemy Changing value of field in association object from the parent

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a relationship between an Events table and a Contacts table where an event can have multiple contacts and one can be marked primary.

I thought I had it, but I can't seem to figure out how to change the primary field that I have in the association object.

Here is the database structure:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy import orm

import uuid

Base = declarative_base()
Session = orm.sessionmaker()
Engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///arandomdb', echo=True)
Session.configure(bind=Engine)
session = Session()


class TblEvents(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_events'
    guid = sa.Column(sa.String(36), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)

    contacts = orm.relationship('TblContacts', secondary='tbl_events_contacts', backref='events')


class TblContacts(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'tbl_contacts'

    guid = sa.Column(sa.String(36), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)


class TblEventsContacts(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'tbl_events_contacts'

    event_id = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.ForeignKey(TblEvents.guid), primary_key=True)
    contact_id = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.ForeignKey(TblContacts.guid), primary_key=True)
    primary = sa.Column(sa.Boolean)

    event = orm.relationship('TblEvents',
                             backref=orm.backref('tbl_events_contacts',
                                                 passive_deletes='all'
                             ))
    contact = orm.relationship('TblContacts',
                               backref=orm.backref('tbl_events_contacts',
                                                   passive_deletes='all'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.create_all(Engine)

    ev1 = TblEvents(guid=str(uuid.uuid4()), name='event 1')
    con1 = TblContacts(guid=str(uuid.uuid4()), name='contact 1')
    session.add(ev1, con1)
    session.commit()

    ev1.contacts.append(con1)
    session.commit()

    ev1.contacts[0].primary = True
    session.commit()
```

It doesn't complain about trying to set ev1.contacts[0].primary = True but it also doesn't seem to do anything.

What is the proper way of going about this data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contacts property of your event object references TblContacts objects-- not TblEventsContacts association objects.

To get a reference to a tblEventsContacts object from a TblEvents object, you'd need to use the backreference that you defined for that association (tbl_events_contacts).

In other words, change:

```
ev1.contacts[0].primary = True
```

To:

```
ev1.tbl_events_contacts[0].primary = True
```

And you should have better luck.

Comment: Oh, right, that makes a ton of sense. I'll give it a try when I get back home.